# RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView return 204 http status when receive Delete request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is my class-based view:

```
class BookDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

When i send the delete request http://10.0.3.2:8000/ecard/book/id=2/, http status 204 is returned, the book is successfully deleted, but how can i get the 200 status in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: http://www.cdrf.co/3.1/rest_framework.mixins/DestroyModelMixin.html

```
 def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        self.perform_destroy(instance)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Just rewrite your desire status code, in my case is status.HTTP_200_OK